# Pandas: Create a new column based on a another column which is a list of objects

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, lambda

I am trying to create/add a new column into the following dataframe (df_new):

[image: Dataframe sample]

I want this new column (df['category']) to be feed from df['tags'].

The tags columns, is a list of objects, and the value that I want to retrieve is the category, and if there is no category I want to set it as unknown.

This is a sample of my JSON file

```
{"submissionTime":"2019-02-25T09:26:00","b_data":{"bName":"Masato","b_Acc":[{"id":0,"transactions":[{"date":"2019-12-19","text":"PERIODICAL PAYMENT","amount":3397,"type":"","tags":[{"institution":"University of MC"},{"lenderType":"private"},{"category":"birdy"},{"creditDebit":"credit"}]},{"date":"2019-12-03","text":"LINE FEE","amount":-460.21,"type":"Overdrawn Fees","tags":[{"category":"Overdrawn"},{"creditDebit":"debit"}]},{"date":"2019-12-31","text":"INTEREST","amount":-871.62,"type":"Interest Charge","tags":[{"category":"Fees"},{"creditDebit":"debit"}]},{"date":"2019-12-31","text":"LOAN SERVICE FEE","amount":-120,"type":"Loan Related Fees","tags":[{"category":"Fees"},{"creditDebit":"debit"}]},{"date":"2019-12-18","text":"PERIODICAL PAYMENT","amount":3397,"type":"","tags":[{"institution":"University of MC"},{"lenderType":"private"},{"category":"birdy"},{"creditDebit":"credit"}]},{"date":"2019-12-02","text":"LINE FEE","amount":-498.34,"type":"Overdrawn Fees","tags":[{"category":"Overdrawn"},{"creditDebit":"debit"}]},{"date":"2019-11-29","text":"INTEREST","amount":-794.4,"type":"Interest Charge","tags":[{"category":"Fees"},{"creditDebit":"debit"}]},{"date":"2019-11-19","text":"PERIODICAL PAYMENT","amount":3397,"type":"","tags":[{"institution":"University of MC"},{"lenderType":"private"},{"category":"birdy"},{"creditDebit":"credit"}]},{"date":"2019-11-01","text":"LINE FEE","amount":-484.87,"type":"Overdrawn Fees","tags":[{"category":"Overdrawn"},{"creditDebit":"debit"}]},{"date":"2019-10-31","text":"INTEREST","amount":-882.04,"type":"Interest Charge","tags":[{"category":"Fees"},{"creditDebit":"debit"}]},{"date":"2019-10-21","text":"PERIODICAL PAYMENT","amount":3397,"type":"","tags":[{"institution":"University of MC"},{"lenderType":"private"},{"category":"birdy"},{"creditDebit":"credit"}]},{"date":"2019-10-01","text":"LINE FEE","amount":-503.59,"type":"Overdrawn Fees","tags":[{"category":"Overdrawn"},{"creditDebit":"debit"}]},{"date":"2019-09-30","text":"INTEREST","amount":-916.98,"type":"Interest Charge","tags":[{"category":"Fees"},{"creditDebit":"debit"}]},{"date":"2019-09-30","text":"LOAN SERVICE FEE","amount":-120,"type":"Loan Related Fees","tags":[{"category":"Fees"},{"creditDebit":"debit"}]},{"date":"2019-09-19","text":"PERIODICAL PAYMENT","amount":3397,"type":"","tags":[{"institution":"University of MC"},{"lenderType":"private"},{"category":"birdy"},{"creditDebit":"credit"}]},{"date":"2019-09-02","text":"LINE FEE","amount":-489.65,"type":"Overdrawn Fees","tags":[{"category":"Overdrawn"},{"creditDebit":"debit"}]},{"date":"2019-08-30","text":"INTEREST","amount":-892.13,"type":"Interest Charge","tags":[{"category":"Fees"},{"creditDebit":"debit"}]}]}]}}
```

and this is how I have been able to do so far:

```
import json
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

with open('question.json') as json_data:
    d = json.load(json_data)

df = pd.json_normalize(d['b_data']['b_Acc'])

frames = []

#https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/merging.html
for index, row in df.iterrows():
    frames = frames + row['transactions']

df_new = pd.DataFrame(frames)

df['category'] = df_new['tags'].apply(pd.Series)[0]
```

This chould potentially work if category is always the first element of that array, however in raw 0 the first element is institution, the second raw is creditDebit (which i would like to be unknow as there is no category)

Answer (score 0):

This will do what you did in for loop

```
s=pd.DataFrame(pd.DataFrame(df.transactions.tolist()).stack().str['tags'].tolist())
```

Comment: Thank you that is a good line to replace the loop, but still missing hte part of creating the new column based on that object category of each record

Comment: I am sorry, I am a bit confused, which update? the answer still shows me the same

Comment: @Manza sorry about that forget add str ~

Comment: That is really cool, but if you see the original image what I want is create a new column in that original dataframe, so still have date, text, amount, type, tags and the new column "category" that extract the category object from the tags

Comment: I have amended the question a little bit, but I added a new line I guess I am looking something like this: df['category'] = df_new['tags'].apply(pd.Series)[0], however that is not correct as element 0 is not necessarily category, i will need somehow to look to extract the cat value